# Using Mouseover event multiple times not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do a hover effect on some text. When I mouse over it, I want the text to be displayed with a close box. When I hit the close box, I obviously want it to close until I mouse over it again and get it to display again.

I'm able to display the hover text once, but after closing it the first time, it won't come back. I'm not really sure what is wrong... any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to jquery/javascript in general so I might be missing something very obvious!

```
<div class ="closethis" id="one">
   Text 
        <div id="two"> 
            <ul> Hover text <div class="close"></div> </ul>                
</div>
```

The above is the basic setup, here is my javascript:

```
$("#one").on("mouseover", function() {
  $("#two ul").addClass('permhover');
});

$('.closethis').hover(function(){
$(this).find('.close').animate({opacity:1},100)
    })                
    $('.close').click(function(){$(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');});
```

For the css setup and the jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/mmrVU/65/ There is just a placeholder square right now for the close icon but it works.

Thank you!

Comment: Please note that `<ul>` is for unordered lists, and putting anything other than `<li>` elements in it is invalid according to the [W3C HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

Comment: Oh whoops. I'm new :P I think I needed it to get the javascript working, but maybe I was missing something. What should I use instead?

Comment: `<div>` would be the "catch-all" element. It's described as: **The div element is a generic container for flow content that by itself does not represent anything.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is css specificity. When you do `fadeOut` it adds an inline style of `display:none` to the element and even though you add the class it does not matter since inline style overrides the rule. Also generally it would be better to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` since `mouseover` events bubble up (In the code just try using mouseover you will see that element just shows up when you move your mouse and even after close and when you are not hovering the text). Also note that you are adding `permHover` class on mouseover every time which is not needed since you are never removing them. Similarly you do not need to use animate as well as adding opacity does not make any difference in your case.

Try:

```
$("#one").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $("#two ul").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7L8qA/)**

Answer (score 1):

1. The `fadeOut()` set the display to none but `animate()` doesn't change that so use `fadeIn()`
2. Use `mouseenter` instead of `hover` because else the same function will get called on mouse leave also
3. You need to use animate on the `permhover` element

Try

```
$('.closethis').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.permhover').stop(true, true).fadeIn()
})
$('.close').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.permhover').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vrY4L/)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the opacity to 0 on close. You need to set it back to 100%.